# Max path sum algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, programming-challenge

This is for [Project Euler question 18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) and I'm looking for feedback on whether my algorithm is incorrect or whether I've just implemented it wrong (which I don't think is the case after some testing).

The question is to traverse the maximum path in a triangle from top to bottom.

> ```
>                             75
>                           95  64
>                         17  47  82
>                       18  35  87  10
>                     20  04  82  47  65
>                   19  01  23  75  03  34
>                 88  02  77  73  07  63  67
>               99  65  04  28  06  16  70  92
>             41  41  26  56  83  40  80  70  33
>           41  48  72  33  47  32  37  16  94  29
>         53  71  44  65  25  43  91  52  97  51  14
>       70  11  33  28  77  73  17  78  39  68  17  57
>     91  71  52  38  17  14  91  43  58  50  27  29  48
>   63  66  04  68  89  53  67  30  73  16  69  87  40  31
> 04  62  98  27  23  09  70  98  73  93  38  53  60  04  23
> ```

Starting from the second bottom row, each value is its current value + `max(left child, right child)`, which transforms each position in the tree to be its max path sum from that point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using Tree = vector<vector<int>>;

void transform_mps(Tree& tree) {
    // start from bottom up, each node's value is node.val + max(left child, right child)
    // transforms tree such that each node is that node's max path sum
    for (int layer = tree.size() - 2; layer >= 0; --layer) {
        for (size_t pos = 0; pos < tree[layer].size(); ++pos) {
            tree[layer][pos] = tree[layer][pos] + max(tree[layer+1][pos], tree[layer+1][pos+1]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) { cout << "Need to pass in file to read from\n"; return 1; }

    ifstream f {argv[1]};
    if (!f.is_open()) { cout << "Could not open file\n"; return 1; }

    Tree tree;
    string line;
    while (getline(f, line)) {
        istringstream is {line};
        tree.push_back(vector<int>(istream_iterator<int>(is), istream_iterator<int>()));
    }
    transform_mps(tree);
    int mps {tree[0][0]};
    cout << "Max path sum: " << mps << endl;
}

/********** leftovers from previous implementation, ignore
constexpr bool LEFT {false};
constexpr bool RIGHT {true};

int pathsum(Tree& tree, size_t layer, size_t pos, bool right) {
    int sum {};
    ++layer;    // next level
    for (; layer < tree.size(); ++layer) 
        if (right) sum += tree[layer][++pos];
        else sum += tree[layer][pos];
    return sum;
}
***********/
```

Comment: At a first glance this looks strucurally similar to my Python implementation, but it seems that the pathsum function isn't used and isn't needed...

Comment: Also note that the tree is altered during execution. Maybe not what a user of this function might expect...

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me, algorithmically and syntactically. What makes you think it's wrong?

Stylistically, there are a few things you could improve:

- Don't `using namespace std`. It's more idiomatic and readable to explicitly qualify `std::max`, `std::cout`, etc., and it's not much more typing.
- Don't comment out dead code; delete it instead. ;)
- `tree[layer][pos] = tree[layer][pos] + ...;` should be simply
  `tree[layer][pos] += ...;`

And algorithmically, notice that if you start at the **top** of the tree and work **downward**, you don't need to store O(*Rows*²) numbers; you just need to store the previous row's sums, for a total space cost of O(*Rows*). (And then at the end you have *Rows* possible answers, and you pick the [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) of all of them.)

- This might be a Project Euler constraint; but in the Unix/Linux world, it's more traditional to get your input from `stdin` rather than reading a filename off the command line. (Most utility programs support both, of course. The only one I know of that doesn't is [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr).) Combine that with the top-down approach, and you get a nice Unixy stream filter that makes just one single pass over the data.

Answer (score -1):

That the tree is modified is not an issue for me. Your function takes the tree by non-const reference, and if you want to keep the original you can always "store" the original.

That you read from a file is not an issue either. The algorithm has been separated from the way that data was read in.

I would probably have gone around creating some nice OO DAG and then use depth-first or breadth-first search. But then mine would be more generic for DAGs in general.

Either way, in my solution I would return the path itself as well as the result, something yours does not do.